# Identifier out of scope

Tags: c#, c++, .net, command-line-interface

I have this C++/CLI application that I made a few years back. It has an `Engine_Base` class with  a bunch of different classes that inherits from the base and the settings of the app are used to tell which engine it should use.

I have to refactor part of this application in the past couple of weeks and I am now getting some very strange behavior.

While setting all the components up, there is a place in the code where the logic is to instantiate the right engine:

```
if (this->M_ENGINE == "EngineX") {
    engine_for_app = static_cast<EDI::EDI_Engine_Base^>(
        gcnew EDI::EDI_Engine_EngineX(
            sTemplate, 
            this->m_sDeliveryFilePath, 
            this->M_DBNAME, 
            this->M_DBSERVER, 
            this->M_CUSTOMER_ID, 
            Application::ExecutablePath, 
            this->cBoxDeliveryDateFormat->SelectedIndex, 
            this->M_SO_CREATION,     
            this->M_SO_CREATION_STATUS));
}
```

The engine classes are in C# and their constructors calls the base engine constructor as such:

```
public EDI_Engine_EngineX(String sDeliveryTemplatePath, String sDeliveryFilePath, String sDbName, String sDbServer, String sCustId, String sAppPath, int iDelDateFormat, String sSOCreation, String sSOCreationStatus)
        : base(sDbName, sDbServer, sCustId, sAppPath, sSOCreation, sSOCreationStatus)
{
    //...Stuff that this particular engine needs to set...
}
```

This sends the execution to the engine base class' constructor:

```
EDI_Engine_Base::EDI_Engine_Base(String^ sDbName, String^ sDbServer, String^ sCustId, 
    String^ sAppPath, String^ sSOCreation, String^ sSOCreationStatus)
{
    //...yada yada yada setting stuff in the base class...
}
```

Ok...Sorry for taking so long to get to the point, but all the pieces are in place now.

The problem that I get is that until execution gets to the base class constructor all the parameters are fine. By that I mean they are instantiated and populated. As I get to the base class constructor, the string sDbServer is not even instantiated. I get a "Identifier is out of scope" when I try a quick watch on it.

Considering that it is a simple string, that it is instantiated at the same time as sDbName, that with breakpoints I have validated that the value is passed to the instance class and that at the moment the base constructor the value is still there. I don't understand what is going on at all.

All of this was working until yesterday, but I have not touched this code.

Anyone has ideas or theories about what is going on?

EDIT: I have found the answer.

Comment: Why remove the C# tag when the engine classes are C#? This may be relevant.

Comment: My mistake. Didn't read quite carefully enough -- apologies. Re-added.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the parameter has been changed in the refactoring and the constructor definition (in the .h) had a different name for this parameter which caused the runtime error.

I would have thought this kind of errors to be caught by the compiler, but I guess they aren't.

Comment: The compiler only looks at your source code, not your watch expressions.  Same with most refactoring tools. So yes, it's easy for watch expressions to become invalid as a result of refactoring.